# gssapi requires Ruby version >= 1.9.1. on gem install

Tags: ruby, rubygems, knife

I'm trying to install `knife-cloudstack` plugin using gem install on Ubuntu 12.04 with chef-client configured and got error as said in title.

```
>gem install knife-cloudstack
ERROR: Error installing knife-cloudstack:
       gssapi requires Ruby version >= 1.9.1
```

So i tried installing `apt-get install ruby1.9.3`, but still the same error.

Also, the version of ruby is shown 1.9.3

> ruby --version
>       ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [i686-linux]

To get more confused, when i run `sudo update-alternatives --config ruby` , its showing output as:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative ruby (providing /usr/bin/ruby).

     Selection    Path                Priority   Status
   ------------------------------------------------------------
     0            /usr/bin/ruby1.8     50        auto mode
     1            /usr/bin/ruby1.8     50        manual mode
   * 2            /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1   10        manual mode

   Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

PS: Initially the * was on Selection:0, i changed it later to 2.

Now where is ruby1.9.3? Even if i installed ruby1.9.3, why its taking other version?Anyone knowing what's causing the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package is called 1.9.1 because that is the ABI version.

> Ruby uses two parallel versioning schemes: the `Ruby library
>   compatibility version' (1.9.1 for this package), which is similar to a
>   library SONAME, and the 'Ruby version' (1.9.3 for this package). Ruby
>   packages in Debian are named using the Ruby library compatibility
>   version, which is sometimes confusing for users who do not follow Ruby
>   development closely. This package depends on the ruby1.9.1 package,
>   and provides compatibility symbolic links from 1.9.3 executables and
>   manual pages to their 1.9.1 counterparts.

Comment: But as from the error, it needs a ruby version of 1.9.1 or greater,rt and i have 1.9.3 installed. But still its not taking. What can be the possible reason for that?

Comment: @HRM What does `gem env` say?

Comment: Ohkk...Here it is..RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.15, RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352)[i686-linux], which means its the old version, rt?

Comment: @HRM Yep, that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks man for giving me the hint. I just reinstalled rubygems and now that error goes, some other pops out!!...trying to figure that out..

Answer (score 2):

I've just come across this same issue when trying to install knife-rackspace. The issue stems from what @xdazz says in a comment

> What does gem env say?

Essentially it is not enough to update alternatives for ruby, but you have to do it for gem too

```
sudo update-alternatives --config ruby
sudo update-alternatives --config gem
```

Once gem env reports the right version of ruby then you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the remaining versions:

```
apt-get purge ruby1.8
apt-get purge ruby
```

Now check versions are available

```
~# update-alternatives --config ruby
```

There is 1 choice for the alternative ruby (providing `/usr/bin/ruby`).

```
  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1   10        auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1   10        manual mode
```

Now you can install knife-cloudstack.